# Where do these limitations on wingspan come from?

Tags: aircraft-design, regulations

[image]

> There may be a limitation on the maximum value of wing span in some
> cases, for example naval aircraft. Airlines have to be able to operate
> into airport gates of limited width and typical values of span for
> different classes of transport aircraft are given in Table 5.2.

Aircraft Conceptual Design Synthesis by Denis Howe

I thought this might be [Aeroplane Design Groups](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Airplane_Design_Group_(ADG)), but the values don't match up. Does anyone know where these values come from? Also, how does the B757 get away with a greater wingspan?

Comment: The text says the values in that chart are "typical," not regulatory.  Perhaps there is less authority to the values there than it appears; the B-737 wingspan is 117', and it along with the A-320 pretty well define short/medium haul airliner, though it'd be too big for that category according to that table.

Comment: Are you asking where the actual wingspan figures in table 5.2 come from, or why there are limitations?

Comment: The B757 was designed as a variant of the B767, so for many purposes it needs to be treated as a wide/heavy plane too even though it may not technically qualify.

Comment: @MichaelHall I was looking for some regulation or convention that I could point to. I'm designing a short-haul aircraft for an assignment. Currently, my wing is a little longer than the short haul requirement (given AR and S). But it fits comfortably within an ICAO and FAA category. If I want it to be suited for short-haul as per Howe's recommendations I'd have to trim my wingspan with winglets or lower the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Two points appear relevant here.

First, all aircraft designers have exactly the same laws of physics to work against, and the same rules of materials science to work with, and those considerations also define the design of the engines used to power their aircraft.

This means that an Airbus is going to closely resemble a Boeing that was designed for the same stage lengths and payload, right down to the fuselage lengths and length-to-diameter ratio, wingspan, wing aspect ratio, sweep angle, overall dry weight, useful load, fuel capacity and engine thrust.

Second, it then becomes the responsibility of the airport terminal designer to accommodate those fuselage lengths, wingspans, and tire loads on the pavement in such a manner as to prevent interference between adjacent planes while being maneuvered into position at their gates and prevent the pavement from cracking under the tire loads.

Since a big airport has to accommodate a variety of plane sizes, the airport designer has to position the gates to accommodate not just a 737 but almost everything else- and the optimum design is one in which the biggest planes get handled by gates at the convexities of the terminal and the smallest ones are serviced by the ones in the resulting concavities.